# Is there an easy way to custom fill null values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null, nan

I have the following DataFrame:

```
     A    B    C    D
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  NaN  2.0  2.0  2.0
3  NaN  3.0  3.0  3.0
4  NaN  4.0  4.0  NaN
5  NaN  NaN  5.0  NaN
6  NaN  NaN  6.0  NaN
```

I am working to generate visualizations with this data, and I need to fill the null values in a very specific way. I want to loop the existing values repeatedly for each column until the null values are all filled, so that the DataFrame looks like this:

```
     A    B    C    D
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  0.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
3  1.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
4  0.0  4.0  4.0  0.0
5  1.0  0.0  5.0  1.0
6  0.0  1.0  6.0  2.0
```

Is there any convenient way to do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

You can [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) a custom function on each column that obtains the values to be iterated and then extends them to the full length of the dataframe. This can be done using [`np.resize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html) as follows:

```
def f(x):
    vals = x[~x.isnull()].values
    vals = np.resize(vals, len(x))
    return vals
    
df = df.apply(f, axis=0)
```

Result:

```
     A    B    C    D
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  0.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
3  1.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
4  0.0  4.0  4.0  0.0
5  1.0  0.0  5.0  1.0
6  0.0  1.0  6.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is with a for loop; the assumption is that the NaNs are at the end of each column, if any. Use `np.place` to fill the nulls :

```py
 [np.place(df[col].to_numpy(), 
           df[col].isna(), 
           df[col].dropna().array) 
   for col in df 
   if df[col].hasnans]

[None, None, None]

df
     A    B    C    D
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  0.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
3  1.0  3.0  3.0  3.0
4  0.0  4.0  4.0  0.0
5  1.0  0.0  5.0  1.0
6  0.0  1.0  6.0  2.0
```

Note that `np.place` is an in place operation, no assignment is needed.

Answer (score -1):

Just do

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(....).fillna(0.0)
```

Comment: I don't believe this accomplishes the goal, as it will just mark everything with a 0.